# Averaged convergence of $a_n^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

Fix $p>0$, and let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence of nonnegative real numbers ($0\le a_n\le 1$ for each $n$) whose Cesaro means $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ have a limit as $n\to +\infty$. Do the Cesaro means of $a_n^p$, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p,$$ have a limit as well?

It is well known that for bounded sequences the formally weaker condition that the Abel means converge, automatically implies the convergence of the Cesaro means; so the question seems to look reasonable. If results of such type exists, references will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can do this quite neatly for $p\geq1$ using generating functions:

- $a_n$ is convergent $\iff\sum_na_nx^n=O(\frac{1}{1-x})$ as $x\to1^-$
- Calling $c_p(n):=\frac{a_1^p+a_2^p+...+a_n^p}{n}$, the condition tells us that $\sum_nc_1(n)x^n=O(\frac{1}{1-x})$ as $x\to1^-$
- Noting that $0\leq a_n\leq1$, one can easily show that $c_p(n)\leq c_1(n)$ for $p>1$
- We thus obtain, virtually for free, that $\sum_nc_p(n)x^n=O(\frac{1}{1-x})$ as $x\to1^-$, and thus that $c_p(n)$ converges also.

Will continue to think about the $0<p<1$ case.

[EDIT: On reflection, I can only comfortably prove that $a_n=O(1)\iff\sum_na_nx^n=O(\frac{1}{1-x})$ as $x\to1^-$. Still think there might be some legs in this approach so going to work on it.]